# Finding $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{n}\sum_{k=1}^n(\alpha(k)-\beta(k))$, where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ count even and odd divisors, respectively

Tags: number-theory, limits, divisor-counting-function

For every $n\in \mathbb{N}^{*}$, let $\alpha(n)$ be the number of even divisors of n and $\beta(n)$ be the number of odd divisors of n. Calculate:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n}\cdot \sum_{k=1}^{n}(\alpha(k)-\beta(k))$$

Comment: Think : shouldn't the *total* number of divisors be much much smaller than the number itself? Come up with a bound for the number of divisors of a number in terms of its prime factorization. Use the squeeze theorem.

Comment: I tried to do that but I couldn't find a bound for the number of odd or even divisors specifically.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Not *too* small though. In fact, $\sum_{k=1}^n \sigma_0(k)= n\log n+(2\gamma-1)n+O(\sqrt n)$, so there's plenty of room for divergent terms in that series $\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n\left(1-\frac2{1+\operatorname{dlog}_2 k}\right)\sigma_0(k)$

Comment: Oh, so it is not that easy. Pardon me, it was my thought that the thing could work. This is quite a good question then! +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote the sums of the $\alpha(k)$ and $\beta(k)$ by $A(n)$ and $B(n)$ respectively.

When counting the odd divisors of $1,2,..., n$ we are counting the number of multiples of $1,3,5,...$ which are no greater than $n$ and so

$$B(n)=  n+ \left \lfloor{\frac{n}{3}}\right \rfloor+\left \lfloor{\frac{n}{5}}\right \rfloor+...$$
Similarly,
$$A(n)=  \left \lfloor{\frac{n}{2}}\right \rfloor+\left \lfloor{\frac{n}{4}}\right \rfloor+\left \lfloor{\frac{n}{6}}\right \rfloor+...$$

Thus $$\frac{B(n)-A(n)}{n}\approx\frac{1}{1\times2}+\frac{1}{3\times4}+\frac{1}{5\times6}+... $$

Comment: I got it now. Thank you!!

Comment: Glad to be of help.